# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID while accessing google.com (Only in chrome)

Tags: google-chrome

I have installed latest Chrome Version 68.0.3440.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)
on Windows 7 Home Premium

When I access google.com/youtube.com I get following error:
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.google.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

1. I have tried importing the certificate as mentioned in [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate), but that didn't help
2. I can access google.com from Mozilla Firefox without any error
3. My laptop time is up to date

Any pointers will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by Installing the certificate from :  https://secure.globalsign.net/cacert/Root-R2.crt in chrome